DataGridView Column Headers Displaying in Another Language
When I look at my DataGridView in Visual Studio, the column headers are all listed in some other language as shown in the image below:

However, when I pull up the "Edit Columns" window for the DataGridView all the columns are written correctly in Spanish (my language):

Creating another DataGridView doesn't fix the problem. This even happens when I try to write in a TextBox, so it doesn't seem to be an issue with this specific DataGridView.
How can I fix this so my columns (and other text elements) display in the correct language as shown in the "Edit Columns" window?

i think you have the wrong font style something like wingdings or so see here how to change it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/ux-guidelines/fonts-and-formatting-for-visual-studio?view=vs-2022

Is there any update? Does the answer solve your problem?

You gave  the wrong font style in you settings
Microsoft describes in his https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/ux-guidelines/fonts-and-formatting-for-visual-studio?view=vs-2022

This is primarily done through the Fonts and Colors page in the Tools > Options dialog.

